# Could my AWS load balancer handle HTTP OPTION requests immediately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, http

HTTP preflight OPTION requests come in a lot and all our system does is reply with some constant headers.

I don't want to fire up my servlet just to find out it's an OPTION request and respond immediately with the required headers.

I'm thinking there should be a way for the load-balancer to do that. Like when I used Apache as a reverse-proxy server to send requests to the Java application server, I think I could easily make it handle the OPTION requests with immediate reply (after all, that's happening on the HTTP layer).

I think it would reduce workload even for the load balancers and the AWS network if they were to spit out the canned reply every time.

Is there any way I can have the AWS load balancer do that?

Comment: I don't think so. This page suggests CloudFront can cache OPTION requests, plus CloudFront has a free tier with 1TB of data each month https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly how you want to respond to these requests, you can use AWS WAF and attach this to the ELB.

Create a custom rule (to block traffic by using "option"):
[image]

Then create a custom response body for this in the Web ACLs.

Custom response bodies are plain text, JSON, or HTML content that you use to customize a response to blocked requests. You can use a response body anywhere in the web ACL where you create it.

... the downside here is WAF is a pay-for addon but it's not much, depending on your budget.